# Kubernetes: Nodes/Pods not showing with kubectl after building cluster with kubeadm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I am trying to create a `Kubernetes cluster` using kubeadm tool. For this I installed the supported `docker version` as specified [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.10.md)

I could also install `kubeadm` successfully. I initiated the cluster with below command

```
 sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/14 --apiserver-advertise-address=172.16.0.11
```

and I got the message to use `kubeadm join` to join the cluster as shown below

```
 Your Kubernetes control-plane has initialized successfully!

 To start using your cluster, you need to run the following as a regular user:

 mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
 sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
 sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

 You should now deploy a pod network to the cluster.
 Run "kubectl apply -f [podnetwork].yaml" with one of the options listed at:
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/

 Then you can join any number of worker nodes by running the following on each as root:

 kubeadm join 172.16.0.11:6443 --token ptdibx.r2uu0s772n6fqubc \
--discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:f3e36a8e82fb8166e0faf407235f12e256daf87d0a6d0193394f4ce31b50255c
```

Used `flannel` for networking purpose

```
  $ kubectl apply -f    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/2140ac876ef134e0ed5af15c65e414cf26827915/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
  podsecuritypolicy.policy/psp.flannel.unprivileged created
  clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel created
  clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel created
  serviceaccount/flannel created
  configmap/kube-flannel-cfg created
  daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64 created
  daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64 created
```

After that when I try to check the `kubectl` command to check the `pods/nodes` status it fails

```
   $ sudo kubectl get nodes
   error: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable

   $ sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
   error: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable

   $ echo $KUBECONFIG 
   /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf:/home/ltestzaman/.kube/config
```

`Docker` and `kubernetes` version are as follows:

```
    $ sudo kubeadm version
    kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2",      
    GitCommit:"52c56ce7a8272c798dbc29846288d7cd9fbae032", GitTreeState:"clean",  
     BuildDate:"2020-04-16T11:54:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

   $ sudo docker version
   Client:
   Version:      17.03.0-ce
   API version:  1.26
   Go version:   go1.7.5
   Git commit:   3a232c8
   Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:10:07 2017
   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

   Server:
   Version:      17.03.0-ce
```

How to make the cluster work?

Output of admin.conf is as follows:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUN5RENDQWJDZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBREFWTVJNd0VRWURWUVFERXdwcmRXSmwKY201bGRHVnpN
QjRYRFRJd01EUXhPREV6TlRnek1sb1hEVE13TURReE5qRXpOVGd6TWxvd0ZURVRNQkVHQTFVRQpBeE1LYTNWaVpYSnVaWFJsY3pDQ0FTSXdEUVlKS29aSWh2Y05BUUVCQlFBRGdnRVBBRENDQVFvQ2dnRUJBSjdvCnhERGVP
UWd4TGsyWE05K0pxc0hYRkRPWHB2YXYxdXNyeXNYMldOZzlOOVFaeDVucFA2UTRpYkQrZDFjWFcyL0oKY0ZXUjhBSDliaG5hZlhLRUhiUVZWT0R2UTcwbFRmNXVtVlQ4Qk5ZUjRQTmlCWjFxVDNMNnduWlYrekl6a0ZKMwp0
eVVNK0prUy80K2dMazI3b01HMFZ4Rnpjd1ozREMxWEFqRXVxb3FrYVF5UGUzMk9XZmZ2N082TjhxeWNCNkdnClNxbWxNWldBMk1DL0J1cFpZWXRYNkUyYUtNUloxZjkzRlpCaFdYNG9DYjVQSGdSUEdoNTFiNERKZExoYlk4
aWMKdVRSa0EyTi95UDVrTlRIMW5pSTU3bTlUY2phcDZpV0p3dFhsdlpOTUpCYmhQS1VjTEFhZG1tTHFtWTNMTmhiaApGZ2orK0s4T3hXVk5KYWVuQnI4Q0F3RUFBYU1qTUNFd0RnWURWUjBQQVFIL0JBUURBZ0trTUE4R0Ex
VWRFd0VCCi93UUZNQU1CQWY4d0RRWUpLb1pJaHZjTkFRRUxCUUFEZ2dFQkFHS2VwQURtZTEva0orZWpob3p4RXVIdXFwQTYKT3dkK3VNQlNPMWYzTTBmSzkxQmhWYkxWakZZeEUwSjVqc1BLNzNJM3cxRU5rb2p2UGdnc0pV
NHBjNnoyeGdsVgpCQ0tESWhWSEVPOVlzRVNpdERnd2g4QUNyQitpeEc4YjBlbnFXTzhBVjZ6dGNESGtJUXlLdDAwNmgxNUV1bi9YCmg0ZUdBMDQrRmNTZVltZndSWHpMVmFFS3F2UHZZWVdkTHBJTktWRFNHZ3J3U3cvbnU5
K2g1U09Ddms1YncwbEYKODhZNnlTaHk3U1B6amRNUHdRcks5cmhWY1ZXK1VvS3d6SE80aUZHdWpmNDR0WHRydTY4L1NGVm5uVnRHWkYyKwo2WmJYeE81Z3I2c1NBQU9NK0E1RmtkQlNmcXZDdmwvUzZFQk04V2czaGNjOUZL
cEFCV0tadHNoRlMxOD0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo=
    server: https://172.16.0.11:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUM4akNDQWRxZ0F3SUJBZ0lJS2RLRGs4MUpNKzh3RFFZSktvWklodmNOQVFFTEJRQXdGVEVUTUJFR0ExVUUKQXhNS2EzVmlaWEp
1WlhSbGN6QWVGdzB5TURBME1UZ3hNelU0TXpKYUZ3MHlNVEEwTVRneE16VTRNelphTURReApGekFWQmdOVkJBb1REbk41YzNSbGJUcHRZWE4wWlhKek1Sa3dGd1lEVlFRREV4QnJkV0psY201bGRHVnpMV0ZrCmJXbHVNSUl
CSWpBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRRUZBQU9DQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQW44elI0RlVVM2F1QjluVGkKeWxJV1ZpZ3JkV1dHSXY0bmhsRnZuQU1mWVJyVklrMGN6eTZPTmZBQzNrb01tZ3ZPQnA5MmpsWmlvYXpJUGg1aAovaUR
xalE3dzN4cFhUN1QxT1kySy9mVyt1S1NRUVI3VUx1bjM4MTBoY1ZRSm5NZmV4UGJsczY2R3RPeE9WL2RQCm1tcEEyUFlzL0lwWWtLUEhqNnNvb0NXU1JEMUZIeG1SdWFhYXhpL0hYQXdJODZEN01uWS90KzZJQVIyKzZRM0s
KY2pPRFdEWlRpbHYyMXBCWFBadW9FTndoZ0s2bWhKUU5VRmc5VmVFNEN4NEpEK2FYbmFSUW0zMndid29oYXk1OAo3L0FnUjRoMzNXTjNIQ1hPVGUrK2Z4elhDRnhwT1NUYm13Nkw1c1RucFkzS2JFRXE5ZXJyNnorT2x5ZVl
GMGMyCkZCV3J4UUlEQVFBQm95Y3dKVEFPQmdOVkhROEJBZjhFQkFNQ0JhQXdFd1lEVlIwbEJBd3dDZ1lJS3dZQkJRVUgKQXdJd0RRWUpLb1pJaHZjTkFRRUxCUUFEZ2dFQkFCVDVKckdCS1NxS1VkclNYNUEyQVZHNmFZSHl
1TkNkeWp1cQpIVzQrMU5HdWZSczJWZW1kaGZZN2VORDJrSnJXNldHUnYyeWlBbDRQUGYzYURVbGpFYm9jVmx0RjZHTXhRRVU2CkJtaEJUWGMrVndaSXRzVnRPNTUzMHBDSmZwamJrRFZDZWFFUlBYK2RDd3hiTnh0ZWpacGZ
XT28zNGxTSGQ3TFYKRDc5UHAzYW1qQXpyamFqZE50QkdJeHFDc3lZWE9Rd1BVL2Nva1RJVHRHVWxLTVV5aUdOQk5rQ3NPc3RiZHI2RApnQVRuREg5YWdNck9CR2xVaUlJN0Qvck9rU3IzU2QvWnprSGdMM1c4a3V5dXFUWWp
wazNyNEFtU3NXS1M4UUdNCjZ6bHUwRk4rYnVJbGRvMnBLNmhBZlBnSTBjcDZWQWk1WW5lQVVGQ2EyL2pJeXI3cXRiND0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo=
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQpNSUlFb3dJQkFBS0NBUUVBbjh6UjRGVVUzYXVCOW5UaXlsSVdWaWdyZFdXR0l2NG5obEZ2bkFNZllSclZJazBjCnp5Nk9OZkFDM2tvTW1
ndk9CcDkyamxaaW9heklQaDVoL2lEcWpRN3czeHBYVDdUMU9ZMksvZlcrdUtTUVFSN1UKTHVuMzgxMGhjVlFKbk1mZXhQYmxzNjZHdE94T1YvZFBtbXBBMlBZcy9JcFlrS1BIajZzb29DV1NSRDFGSHhtUgp1YWFheGkvSFh
Bd0k4NkQ3TW5ZL3QrNklBUjIrNlEzS2NqT0RXRFpUaWx2MjFwQlhQWnVvRU53aGdLNm1oSlFOClVGZzlWZUU0Q3g0SkQrYVhuYVJRbTMyd2J3b2hheTU4Ny9BZ1I0aDMzV04zSENYT1RlKytmeHpYQ0Z4cE9TVGIKbXc2TDV
zVG5wWTNLYkVFcTllcnI2eitPbHllWUYwYzJGQldyeFFJREFRQUJBb0lCQVFDQXhjRHJFaVQ2Yk5jUwpFQ2NoK3Z4YytZbnIxS0EvV3FmbktZRFRMQUVCYzJvRmRqYWREbHN6US9KTHgwaFlhdUxmbTJraVVxS3d2bGV2CkZ
6VElZU1loL2NSRlJTak81bmdtcE5VNHlldWpSNW1ub0h4RVFlNjVnbmNNcURnR3kxbk5SMWpiYnV6R3B4YUsKOUpTRlR0SnJCQlpFZkFmYXB1Q04rZE9IR2ovQUZJbWt2ZXhSckwyTXdIem0zelJkMG5UdkRyOUh1dy9IMjE
1RAprNXBHZjluV1ZsNnZxSGZFYVF0S0NNemY2WE5MdEFjcEJMcmNwSExwWEFObVNMWTAvcFFnV0s5eVpkbVA5b0xCCjhvU1J0eFRsZlU0V1RLdERpNlozK0tTSytidnF4MDRGZTJYb2RlVUM3eDN1d3lwamszOXZjSG55UkM
2Tmhlem4KTExJcnVEbVJBb0dCQU1VbG8zRkpVTUJsczYrdHZoOEpuUjJqN2V6bU9SNllhRmhqUHVuUFhkeTZURFVxOFM2aQprSTZDcG9FZEFkeUE4ejhrdU01ZlVFOENyOStFZ05DT3lHdGVEOFBaV2FCYzUxMit6OXpuMXF
3SVg3QjY1M01lCk5hS2Y1Z3FYbllnMmdna2plek1lbkhQTHFRLzZDVjZSYm93Q3lFSHlrV0FXS3I4cndwYXNNRXQ3QW9HQkFNK0IKRGZZRU50Vmk5T3VJdFNDK0pHMHY1TXpkUU9JT1VaZWZRZTBOK0lmdWwrYnRuOEhNNGJ
aZmRUNmtvcFl0WmMzMQptakhPNDZ5NHJzcmEwb1VwalFscEc5VGtVWDRkOW9zRHoydlZlWjBQRlB2em53R1JOUGxzaTF1cUZHRkdyY0dTClJibzZiTjhKMmZqV0hGb2ppekhVb3Rkb1BNbW1qL0duM0RmVEw2Ry9Bb0dBQk8
rNVZQZlovc2ROSllQN003bkEKNW1JWmJnb2h1Z05rOFhtaXRLWU5tcDVMbERVOERzZmhTTUE2dlJibDJnaWNqcU16d1c4ZmlxcnRqbkk1NjM3Mwp3OEI2TXBRNXEwdElPOCt3VXI2M1lGMWhVQUR6MUswWCtMZDZRaCtqd1N
wa1BTaFhTR05tMVh0dkEwaG1mYWkwCmxPcm82c1hSSUEvT0NEVm5UUENJMFFzQ2dZQWZ3M0dQcHpWOWxKaEpOYlFFUHhiMFg5QjJTNmdTOG40cTU0WC8KODVPSHUwNGxXMXFKSUFPdEZ3K3JkeWdzTk9iUWtEZjZSK0V5SDF
NaVdqeS9oWXpCVkFXZW9SU1lhWjNEeWVHRwpjRGNkZzZHQ3I5ZzNOVE1XdXpiWjRUOGRaT1JVTFQvZk1mSlljZm1iemFxcFlhZDlDVCtrR2FDMGZYcXJVemF5CmxQRkZvUUtCZ0E4ck5IeG1DaGhyT1ExZ1hET2FLcFJUUWN
xdzd2Nk1PVEcvQ0lOSkRiWmdEU3g3dWVnVHFJVmsKd3lOQ0o2Nk9kQ3VOaGpHWlJld2l2anJwNDhsL2plM1lsak03S2k1RGF6NnFMVllqZkFDSm41L0FqdENSZFRxTApYQ3B1REFuTU5HMlFib0JuSU1UaXNBaXJlTXduS1Z
BZjZUMzM4Tjg5ZEo2Wi93QUlOdWNYCi0tLS0tRU5EIFJTQSBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCg==
```

Not sure why most of the entries are `null` as shown below

```
$ sudo kubectl config view
  apiVersion: v1
  clusters: null
  contexts: null
  current-context: ""
  kind: Config
  preferences: {}
  users: null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably the kubeconfig file is not setup properly.

```
 mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
 sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
 sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Alternatively, if you are the root user, you can run:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

Also this should work

```
sudo kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

Comment: These steps are executed as I have shared in the output of echo $KUBECONFIG in original description

Comment: as per what you shared it seems to have two paths..can you just do export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf and see if that works?

Comment: check the content of the file...and also run those kubectl commands with -v=10

Comment: shared the output of admin.conf in original description

Comment: does this command work..sudo kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

Comment: Works.  Also changed KUBECONFIG to /home/ltestzaman/.kube/config and it works without the --config parameter

Answer (score 3):

Changed environmental variable `KUBECONFIG` to `/home/ltestzaman/.kube/config` and it works

```
 $ echo $KUBECONFIG 
 /home/ltestzaman/.kube/config

$ kubectl get nodes --all-namespaces
  NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
  kubemaster-001   Ready    master   117m   v1.18.2
```

Or need to mention --config as identified by @Arghya Sadhu

```
 $ sudo kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
   NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
   kubemaster-001   Ready    master   120m   v1.18.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the kubernetes cluster. Either with `minikube start` or if you are connecting to any cloud service, make sure kubernetes is started.